# Read data from ble in android app continuously

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I want to read data from ble hardware continuously in android app via bluetooth.
Connection has done i can send data from app to ble but cant read data from ble.

`onCharactersticChanged` method has to be called when getting some data from ble but this callback method is not calling. and i'm trying to notify to ble but

```
writeChar.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(BLEUtils.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID, BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE_SIGNED);

descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

---

```
  // Enable local notifications
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(writeChar, true);
```

---

```
 boolean succes = gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

its returns `false`

Comment: what do you mean continuously? i think, ble is for transferring small amount of data. you can use it this way but you have to read chunk of data separately.[ for example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#read) `format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16; int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);`

Comment: yes but i am sending data in string and also receives same,problem is callback methods are not calling like onCharactersticChanged() and onCharacteristicRead() etc.

Comment: put your code, not just some part. onCharactersticChanged and onCharacteristicRead

Comment: i didn't get your answer can you ellaborate

Comment: i mean send us your code, add it to your question. don't give us fractions

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you should set the ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE when subscribing to the characteristics. This is my code to do this:

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = getSupportedGattServices();
            for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                if (!service.getUuid().equals(UUID_TARGET_SERVICE))
                    continue;

                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                        service.getCharacteristics();

                // Loops through available Characteristics.
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                    if (!gattCharacteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID_TARGET_CHARACTERISTIC))
                        continue;

                    final int charaProp = gattCharacteristic.getProperties();

                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                        setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Characteristic does not support notify");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }
```

then you can subscribe to the characteristics with NOTIFICATION:

```
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID_DESCRIPTOR);
    descriptor.setValue(enabled?BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
                                :BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

}
```

after this you can start writing to the device:

```
    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (descriptor.getCharacteristic().getUuid().equals(UUID_TARGET_CHARACTERISTIC)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed");
            }

            byte[] data = <Your data here>;
            BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_TARGET_SERVICE);

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service
            .getCharacteristic(UUID_TARGET_CHARACTERISTIC);

            charac.setValue(data);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error subscribing");
        }
    }
```

And you will receive the callback `onCharactersticChanged` for reading, no need to actually call the read operation.

Remember mBluetoohGatt can only handle 1 operation at a time, if you execute another one while the previous one is unfinished, it won't put in queue, but will return false.

Answer (score 1):

If it returns false it usually means you already have a pending GATT operation. You need to structure your code so that you only have one outstanding GATT operation at a time. You need to wait for the corresponding callback to arrive until you can execute the next operation.

Comment: i am doing read and write operation simultaneously,means i am sending some command to ble after that ble will read this respond for this command